# A firewall that does not ask the same question multiple times when the user answers without selecting "remember this setting" checkbox

Tags: windows, gui, firewall

**Gist**

I'm looking for a firewall:

- A firewall that does not ask the same question multiple times when the user answers without selecting "remember this setting" checkbox
- And ideally, that can display dialog boxes in which "remember setting" option is not pre-selected when programs ask for internet access

**Specifics**

I have been having this annoyance with every firewall I used to date (Tiny, Komodo, Norton, AVG, Avast). The problem is as following:

- Naturally, I have programs that I would like to allow internet access all the time; and I also have programs that I would like to block all the time.
- However, I also have programs that I would like to allow internet access only from time to time.
- ***In the second case***, when I am presented with the firewall dialog each time a program wants to access internet, I end up with a dialog box in which the option to remember my answer is preselected. In order to achieve what I want, I have to uncheck this option, and then click either allow or deny.
- Most of the time, this dialogue shows up multiple times one after another (e.g., 3 times in 5 seconds), and I end up having to click 6-10 times each time I don't want to make a permanent decision about a program.

Therefore, I'd like to have a firewall that is configurable accordingly. More specifically, I want:

- Critically, no multiple dialogue boxes one after another (e.g., when a dialogue is answered the answer applies to all subsequent dialogue boxes that would have been otherwise shown in the next 5 minutes or so).
- Ideally dialog boxes that does not come with a preselected "remember this setting" option.
- Ideally, This firewall being part of a larger internet security suite, so I don't have to disable a module in a security suite and install an external firewall.

I would appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: Good question.  I've had the same question.  It's amazing how such a simple issue can really mess up your daily workflow.  Those companies really need to invest more resources into hiring usability experts.

Comment: I'm almost sure you want one for Windows, so I added that tag.  Do you want gratis (freeware) or commercial?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Thanks. Indeed, such issues makes me think whether developers are using their own software. (Or, perhaps they do, but they are really great at making long-term decisions each time the prompt pops up!).

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: True, this is for Windows. And I am open for both freeware or commercial suggestions, although as I previously mentioned, such a firewall would ideally be a part of a full security suite.